# HDMI status in standby mode

Tags: android, android-source, hdmi, android-powermanager

I need to find in AOSP code, where the intent android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG is sent, and after we receive intent android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF, if there is possibility to send android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG intent with extra android.media.extra.AUDIO_PLUG_STATE = 1 , which would mean that HDMI is still connected (so far in logs we have for our box that android.media.extra.AUDIO_PLUG_STATE is equal to 0, after we our box goes to sleep mode, which means that HDMI cable is not connected after we turn off our box, which is not true). So my question is where we can intercept that in AOSP code so that we can change it (inside which classes). I found code like this which may be helpful, which I’m providing in below code snippets?

```
private void sendDeviceConnectionIntent(int device, int state, String address,
                                            String deviceName) {
        if (AudioService.DEBUG_DEVICES) {
            Slog.i(TAG, "sendDeviceConnectionIntent(dev:0x" + Integer.toHexString(device)
                    + " state:0x" + Integer.toHexString(state) + " address:" + address
                    + " name:" + deviceName + ");");
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch(device) {
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET:
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
                intent.putExtra("microphone", 1);
                break;
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE:
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_LINE:
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
                intent.putExtra("microphone", 0);
                break;
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_USB_HEADSET:
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
                intent.putExtra("microphone",
                        AudioSystem.getDeviceConnectionState(AudioSystem.DEVICE_IN_USB_HEADSET, "")
                                == AudioSystem.DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE ? 1 : 0);
                break;
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_IN_USB_HEADSET:
                if (AudioSystem.getDeviceConnectionState(AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_USB_HEADSET, "")
                        == AudioSystem.DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE) {
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
                    intent.putExtra("microphone", 1);
                } else {
                    // do not send ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG when only the input side is seen as changing
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI:
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI_ARC:
            case AudioSystem.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI_EARC:
                configureHdmiPlugIntent(intent, state);
                break;
        }

        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            return;
        }

        intent.putExtra(CONNECT_INTENT_KEY_STATE, state);
        intent.putExtra(CONNECT_INTENT_KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        intent.putExtra(CONNECT_INTENT_KEY_PORT_NAME, deviceName);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);

        final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        try {
            mDeviceBroker.broadcastStickyIntentToCurrentProfileGroup(intent);
        } finally {
            Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(ident);
        }
    }


private void configureHdmiPlugIntent(Intent intent, @AudioService.ConnectionState int state) {
        intent.setAction(AudioManager.ACTION_HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG);
        intent.putExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_AUDIO_PLUG_STATE, state);
        if (state != AudioService.CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED) {
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<AudioPort> ports = new ArrayList<AudioPort>();
        int[] portGeneration = new int[1];
        int status = AudioSystem.listAudioPorts(ports, portGeneration);
        if (status != AudioManager.SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listAudioPorts error " + status + " in configureHdmiPlugIntent");
            return;
        }
        for (AudioPort port : ports) {
            if (!(port instanceof AudioDevicePort)) {
                continue;
            }
            final AudioDevicePort devicePort = (AudioDevicePort) port;
            if (devicePort.type() != AudioManager.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI
                    && devicePort.type() != AudioManager.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI_ARC
                    && devicePort.type() != AudioManager.DEVICE_OUT_HDMI_EARC) {
                continue;
            }
            // found an HDMI port: format the list of supported encodings
            int[] formats = AudioFormat.filterPublicFormats(devicePort.formats());
            if (formats.length > 0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> encodingList = new ArrayList(1);
                for (int format : formats) {
                    // a format in the list can be 0, skip it
                    if (format != AudioFormat.ENCODING_INVALID) {
                        encodingList.add(format);
                    }
                }
                final int[] encodingArray = encodingList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
                intent.putExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_ENCODINGS, encodingArray);
            }
            // find the maximum supported number of channels
            int maxChannels = 0;
            for (int mask : devicePort.channelMasks()) {
                int channelCount = AudioFormat.channelCountFromOutChannelMask(mask);
                if (channelCount > maxChannels) {
                    maxChannels = channelCount;
                }
            }
            intent.putExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT, maxChannels);
        }
    }
```